# Longlist will not update at load

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am having some problems making a long list selector load my data, and i have been unable to find a solution to this problem.

This is my xaml:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="animeList" 
                        Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Animes}"
                        Tap="AnimeList_OnTap">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}">
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="false">
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Add as favorit" Click="AddFavorite" />
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

My view model is simple:

```
public ObservableCollection<AnimeItemViewModel> _animes { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<AnimeItemViewModel> Animes
{
    get { return _animes; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _animes)
        {
            _animes = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Animes");
        }
    }
}
```

And how i load my data:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = App.ViewModel;
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    ObservableCollection<AnimeItemViewModel> _animes = new ObservableCollection<AnimeItemViewModel>();
    foreach (var i in App.AnimeList.List)
        _animes.Add(new AnimeItemViewModel() { AId = i.AId, Name = i.Name });
    App.ViewModel.Animes = _animes;
}
```

And lastly just to show that there are data in the list
[image]

Update: I also have a search function, and if i enter a search text will the longlist update, but i am for some reason unable to scroll

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        ObservableCollection<AnimeItemViewModel> _animes = new ObservableCollection<AnimeItemViewModel>();
        foreach (var i in App.AnimeList.List)
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchTextBox.Text) || i.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchTextBox.Text.ToLower()))
                _animes.Add(new AnimeItemViewModel() { AId = i.AId, Name = i.Name });
        App.ViewModel.Animes = _animes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's try something - take your loading code and place it on the search function (`OnKeyDown`), just to see if it loads fine so I can know if the problem is the code or its position.

Comment: See my update, when i do that, it dose display the data, but the list is stuck, i am unable to scroll it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing your loading code in `OnNavigatedTo`. As for the scrolling issue - setting a proper height to the `StackPanel`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I have tryed loading my code in the OnVavigatedTo, the same problem. You are correct about the scrolling issue, but how can i set a proper height that will work on all devices? I have added all my xaml code to the first post

Comment: if i use auto will it just make the box way to high :(